# 'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, i have facing this issue and got stucked

Tags: ionic-framework

I have purchased ionic mobile template for woo commerce from (https://codecanyon.net/item/ionic-woocommerce-universal-ios-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app/21561737)

When I am trying to execute ionic serve if give the following error:

> 'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command

Please help me out, I am very disturbed due to this.

Comment: Have you run `npm install` before running `ionic serve`? If you have then you could try installing that package with `npm install ionic-app-scripts` and see if that works.

Comment: YES, i have already run "npm install" it is up to  date, when i am create new ionic file then it's working but "ionic serve" is not working with this purchased mobile template. if you  can help me please help me out with this.

Comment: Did you try installing the missing package with `npm install ionic-app-script` ?

Comment: Yes, thank you , it got worked.